# Timeout for Webservice response?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I have a client that calls a webservice.
Partly some of the called methods may take a long time to complete on the server (even up to 1 hour). I want the client to wait for the response for that time, thus keeping the connection alive!

I tried to set the following property within the client, but without success:

```
((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", 0); //0 for disabling any timeouts
```

I'm still getting Timeout Exception after some time. Which property has to be set to prevent the following error?

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization while invoking public abstract boolean my.method
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.createFault(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:213)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.preEjbInvoke(EjbMethodInvoker.java:146)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.invoke(EjbMethodInvoker.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:211)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.onMessage(CxfWsContainer.java:73)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsServlet.service(WsServlet.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization
    at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:335)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:75)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:73)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:258)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:190)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.ejb.EjbMethodInvoker.preEjbInvoke(EjbMethodInvoker.java:119)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:272)
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:328)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Transaction has timed out
    at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:266)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure that this is a client side timeout? Did you configure your server transaction timeout properly?

For client side timeout you need in your cxf configuration:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client ConnectionTimeout="your connection timeout" ReceiveTimeout="your receive timeout"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

Timeouts are expressed in milliseconds.

In Java code you need get the HTTPConduit and then set HTTPClientPolicy:

see from http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

```
  import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
  import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
  import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;
  import org.apache.cxf.transports.http.configuration.HTTPClientPolicy;
  ...

  URL wsdl = getClass().getResource("wsdl/greeting.wsdl");
  SOAPService service = new SOAPService(wsdl, serviceName);
  Greeter greeter = service.getPort(portName, Greeter.class);

  // Okay, are you sick of configuration files ?
  // This will show you how to configure the http conduit dynamically
  Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(greeter);
  HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

  HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();

  httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(your connection timeout); 
  httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
  httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(your receive timeout);

  http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

  ...
  greeter.sayHi("Hello");
```

**Update**

For your `java.lang.ClassCastException` make sure that `com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub` is not in classpath or ensure that cxf jar is before Sun's jaxws RI jar in the classpath. For example try removing jaxws-rt*.jar from your classpath.

Comment: Where do I have to place this?? I have not config file for my webservice. Just an annotation, like `@WebService(
        portName =.. ,
        serviceName =.. ,
        targetNamespace =.. ,
        endpointInterface =.. )`

Comment: so I do not have any cxf config as using `javax.jws.WebService;`

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub cannot
be cast to org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(ClientProxy.java:121)
        at Myclass.getWebservice(Config.java:58)
        at Client.connect(Client.java:37)
        at Client.main(ApplicationRunner.java:28)`

Comment: Hm for the cxf config I would have to use spring right? This is not possible atm. Concerning class loading issue: strange thing is that it occures on [i]client[/i] side! So without any server loading involved...

Comment: Did you try instantiating service with my provided example taken from cxf website?

Comment: Yes I tried exactly this. I had already parts of it like URL, create service, getPort. So I just added the Client stuff.

Comment: If I include ALL libs from my webserver (tomee) within the client program: it works without exception! But these are > 100 libs. How can I identify which library fixes this?

Comment: I got it working by adding ~20 libs to my client. Thare are almost `all cxf libs + neethi + stax2 + wsdl4j + xmlschema-core`. I don't know why I need all those libs, but I tracked it down to the minimum required libs I do not get an exception in any way. With these libs it works as in your example taken from cxf.apache. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you are right and it is really not a client side problem. How would I configure the server side transaction timeout?

Comment: You know how to make it indefinite. I tried commenting `setReceiveTimeout` but that did not work.